# RegEx for Ext js textfield

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex which will allow dot and forward and backward slash. Where dot is mandatory. I am using Ext js 5.0.

Comment: can you give an example of a string?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide an example string and expected output, as well as patterns you've tried.

> allow dot and forward and backward slash.where dot is mandatory.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\.\/?\\?");
```

Comment: Thanks..My field should be like "tellac.co.jp" where one dot is mandatory and it should not allow white space..while copy paste also it should not allow..